# Map for DTO with stream spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have question about map dto to key and value with stream in Spring Boot. I want create something like in example. Can you explain how I can do it without use Kryo framework and copy serialize instance?

For example Person is Set collection.

```
Person
.stream()
.collect(
toMap(PersonSet::Id, and value something like 'this' ));
```

Comment: what is the input and the expected output?

Comment: I want parse Set to Map<Person::Id, Person>

Comment: `PersonSet` is a different type than `Person` ? Or you just want to get `Map<Integer, Person>` out of  `Set<Person>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
final Set<Person> personSet = //create a set of persons;
final Map<Integer, Person> personMap = personSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::id, person -> person).
```

Answer (score 3):

If your Dto look like so :

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    //.. getter and setters
}
```

Then you can use `toMap` like so :

```
Set<Person> set = ...;
Map<Long, Person> result = set.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Person::id` is an integer - to create `Map<Integer, Person>` out of `Set<Person>` you can use something like :

```
Set<Person> people = ...

Map<Integer, Person> collect = people.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function.identity()));
```

using [Collectors::toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector and [Function::identity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--)